# How can I convert a NxN Matrix to a Vector Nx1?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> $$
> \left[
> \begin{array}{@{}ccccc@{}}
> 0.9& 0.1& 0& 0& 0& 0& \\
> 0& 0.9& 0.1& 0& 0& 0& \\
> 0& 0& 0.9& 0& 0& 0.1& \\
> 0& 0& 0& 0.9& 0.1& 0& \\
> 0& 0& 0& 0.1& 0.9& 0& \\
> 0.1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0.9& \\
> \end{array}
> \right]
> $$
>   For example i have this matrix and i want to convert a vector ? is it possible?

Comment: What is a "vector matrix"?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to a vector"? The only thing I can think is associate with the matrix it's coordinates vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ defining a basis to the space $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and then mapping the coeficients used in the linear combination that represents this matrix to the elements of what we call the "coordinate vector" in $\mathbb{R}^m$ related to the basis you've selected. Also, look that $m$ should be the dimension of the space of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many ways to do that in a linear way. As many as there are isomorphisms between $M_N(K)$ and $K^{N^2}$. Two natural ones consist in putting the columns (resp. the rows) on top of each other.